# Visual Studio CSS not working in compiled app

Tags: css, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio 2019 and I am having a bit of a problem with my CSS stylesheet location. I am using the Peachpie.App NuGet and everything works perfectly when I run the Debug (F5) with the correct stylesheet being used but if I run the compiled application executable I loose all of the CSS formatting. I assume I have got the style.css file in the wrong location for the compiling process to pick it up but I don't know how to resolve that, can anyone provide some advice on this?

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 0):

I manually copied the style.css file to the "\bin\Release\net5.0\wwwroot" directory and it resolved the problem but I should have expected that that would have been down during the Build process.